# CakePHP searching for DebugKit at wrong path

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to import DebugKit and CakePHP is producing the following error: `DebugKit.ToolbarComponent could not be found.`

Right below it, it says:

> Create the class ToolbarComponent below in file:
>   /Users/SomeUser/Sites/SomeProject/app/Plugin/DebugKit//Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php

If you notice though, there are two slashes between DebugKit and Controller for some reason, and that's obviously not a real directory. The server running PHP 5.4.17. I have followed the exact installation instructions listed [here](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit). Any suggestions?

Comment: Check in your directory structure whether "app/Plugin/debug_kit / Controller / Component / ToolbarComponent.php" exists or not?

Comment: @ArunJain It actually needs to be `app/Plugin/DebugKit` not `app/Plugin/debug_kit`

Comment: The directory does exist, and it is named DebugKit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the permissions to 755 to folders within DebugKit.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, I realized I had a `Plugin/DebugKit` folder structure in my project's root, **and** under the `app` directory. The one under `app` was empty, save for a blank file called `empty`. Strange. I have no idea how this happened. (Perhaps from accidentally running `composer` as non-root?) I deleted `app/Plugin/DebugKit`, and moved the one from the project root into `app`. No more error.

Answer (score 0):

DebugKit does not currently seem to be compatible with cakephp 3.0 even though it is the example in the documentation.
The latest version still seems to use the 2.x methods.
I will also submit a ticket regarding this to update their documentation to prevent confusion.
If there is something I missed regarding this issue and it is actually possible to install this, let me know.